# Running rqt_gui plugins in Fuerte

Tags: ros, rqt-gui, ros-fuerte, plugin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am having troubles running the rqt_gui in ROS Fuerte.
My system specs:

Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 3.11.0-26-generic
ROS Fuerte

After launching the rqt_gui by running the rosrun command, I recieve the following error message:

```
Could not import "pyqt" bindings of qt_gui_cpp library - so C++ plugins will not be available:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qt_gui_cpp/cpp_binding_helper.py", line 43, in <module>
    import libqt_gui_cpp_sip
ImportError: /opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qt_gui_cpp/libqt_gui_cpp_sip.so: undefined symbol: _ZN3ros7package10getPluginsERKSsS2_RSt6vectorISsSaISsEEb
```

I have two ROS Versions installed. Fuerte and Hydro. The terminal were I started rqt_gui is set up for Fuerte Usage:

```
ROS_ROOT=/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros
ROSLISP_PACKAGE_DIRECTORY=/opt/ros/fuerte/share/common-lisp/ros
ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/user/ROS/fuerte_ws/moro_3rad:/home/user/ROS/fuerte_ws/RCPRG_laser_drivers:/home/user/ROS/fuerte_ws/taurob_simulation:/home/user/ROS/fuerte_ws/taurob_sensors:/home/user/ROS/fuerte_ws/sas_utils:/home/user/ROS/fuerte_ws/sas_ui_server:/home/user/ROS/fuerte_ws/sas_test:/home/user/ROS/fuerte_ws/sas_navigation:/home/user/ROS/fuerte_ws/sas_ecu_client:/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks:/opt/ros/fuerte/share:/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311
ROS_WORKSPACE=/home/user/ROS/fuerte_ws
ROSLISP_PACKAGE_DIRECTORIES=
ROS_DISTRO=fuerte
ROS_ETC_DIR=/opt/ros/fuerte/etc/ros
```

So why is it trying to access the hydro library. In /opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.7/dist-packages I couldn't find any qt_gui_cpp or similar folder. As soon as I try to load a plugin the GUI crashes. For fuerte I can only find this stack

ros-fuerte-rqt - rqt

Is there a way to make rqt_gui workout in Fuerte?

BR and thanks for any help

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/190528/running-rqt_gui-plugins-in-fuerte./) by [Eisenhorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/3282/eisenhorn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 82 on 2014-08-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For me rqt is working fine in fuerte.
I don't have hydro installed, only fuerte and groovy and there are no conflicts.
It might be a problem in your ROS setup.

Can you check your PYTHONPATH environment variable to not contain any hydro paths. It should look similar to this when in a fuerte bash:

```
PYTHONPATH=/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:
```

---

Originally posted by [Dorian Scholz](https://answers.ros.org/users/485/dorian-scholz/) with karma: 391 on 2014-09-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0